# ParameterMirror simpleName is Symbol("<TODO:unnamed>")

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I'm trying to automatically map http query parameters to arguments in a function using mirrors.

When I get the list of parameters the simple name for each param is Symbol("")

I assume this means work in progress.  Anyone know what the plans are for implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a lot of work being done on Mirrors right now, both in the VM and in dart2js. The ParameterMirror functionality is incomplete at the moment, but I expect this will change shortly.

Meanwhile, its a good idea to file bugs when you run into problems like this. You can do that at https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list

Comment: Thanks!  I'll put in a bug.  Note that I posted here since the instructions on the dartlang.org page featured SO fairly prominently.

Comment: Thank you. I've starred it.

Comment: I believe that, even if that worked, you will only be able to get the name of a parameter if it's named.